# SAML Assertion tampering ping federate

Tags: saml-2.0, pingfederate

SAML assertion is generated at the IDP(PF). It is consumed at the SP(PF). Is saml assertion tampering possible? If so, how to test it? I am trying to track get & post requests.

When I post the generated SAML Response to https://machine_name:port_no/sp/ACS.saml2, I get 404 error. I understand that we cannot hit the url.when I give the destination resource url, the resource page is opened.But I don't find the response in my server log.

I want to post the generated response with slight modifications and test if it throws any error. The intruder shouldn't be allowed to get the resource. Though I modify the response, I am able to hit the url & access the page.I am using POSTMAN chrome extension for this purpose.

Note : I am extracting saml response from the Agentless Integration Kit sample application.so the destination url is https://machine_name:port_no/AgentlessIntegrationKitSampleSP

Thanks,
Aswini J

Comment: You say you get 404. Are you sure your sending it to the correct URL. Monitor the trafic and make sure that the you are using the correct URL

Comment: Yes the url is right. It gives me the following exception:
17:41:46,655 WARN  [SoapEndpointUtility] Writing SOAP fault response Invalid Request {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client

Comment: Did you change anything in the request?

Comment: No. Though I don't change anything in the response, it throws the server error

Comment: I am able to tamper the assertion. But I don't know how to post the assertion to the url.

Comment: I am tampering data in my firefox. I got a SAML assertion at IDP. Normally, it will be posted directly onto the url, https://machine_name:port_no/sp/ACS.saml2. . Before the data getting posted on the url, I am aborting the process. I manually try to post the SAML response to the url using POSTER add-on. But I am getting a server error. How do I achieve it? I am doing all these operations to ensure that the protected resource shouldn't be provided to the intruder if he post the assertion on the SP side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to tamper with the SAML data in the browser, you should use the Tamper Data extension for Firefox. It will allow you to step through each transaction and selectively modify the data.

However, you cannot successfully tamper with the SAML Response because it is a digitally signed (and optionally encrypted) message. Any tampering of the signed data will invalidate the message and PingFederate will not allow the message to go through. This is mandated per the SAML XMLDig specification which PF strictly enforces.

The info exchanged between the PingFederate (SP) and QuickStartApp (SP) is not SAML -- it is a "one time use" reference token that refers to information that is stored in PingFederate runtime memory. If you modify this value, PF will throw an error because it will not reference any known data.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ian:) The info exchanged between the PingFederate (SP) and QuickStartApp (SP) is not SAML because we use reference adapter here right? If I use http basic adapter or open token adapter, the reference token will not be sent from PF(SP) to application (SP). Right?

Comment: And I tried to post the saml token to Assertion Consume Service Url. But I am not able to do it. https://machine_name:port_no/sp/ACS.saml2. Not to Quick App url.

Comment: Please try to keep thread to a single topic.  You are correct - the info between PF (SP) and Quickstart App (SP) is not SAML because you are using the SP Reference Adapter for "Last Mile integration". If you used the SP OpenToken Adapter then it would be a different token type specific the Adapter. This would only be relevant to your Application - the IDP has no clue (or care) how you integrate your app. There is no HTTP Basic Adapter (SP) so that wouldn't be an option.